# How to store JavaScript function arguments in PHP Session ?

Tags: javascript, php, session, yii

i have passed argument in JS method and that methods argument needs to save in PHP Session but failed to do so .......
**CODE:**

```
 function checkBoxStatusUser1(condition)
       {

           console.log("condition checkBoxStatusUser1 :"+condition);
           setStatusDataUser(condition);
            <?php
        Yii::app()->session['var'] = condition;
       print_r(Yii::app()->session['var']); // Prints "value"
?>

       }
```

BUT THIS LOC:     Yii::app()->session['var'] = condition;  is not assigning condition's value either true or false to the session

Comment: you must have understand the different between client side execution(js) and server side execution(php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Ajax` for this. If you want to send a javascript variable from client side to server side, you should make an `ajax` call and send the variable in the `'data'` property of the `object parameter` of the `ajax` call.

```
function checkBoxStatusUser1(condition) {
    console.log("condition checkBoxStatusUser1 :" + condition);
    setStatusDataUser(condition);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/requestHandler',
        data: {
            'condition': condition, //here you pass the data
        }
        type: 'post',
    });
}
```

And on server, make a script to handle request at '/requestHandler' and then do this-

```
 Yii::app()->session['var'] = $_POST['condition'];
```

You can get a decent understanding of it here -

http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/

Comment: can u please give me example

Comment: Glad it helped :) Upvoted :D I understand beginners are not entertained on stackoverflow. Even I face a lot of problems in beggining

Comment: can u help me i need to display checkbox in align = right after checkinng session variables value

Comment: $statusMaintain;
        <?php
if(Yii::app()->session['var'])
{
   // print_r(Yii::app()->session['var']);
    $statusMaintain = 'checked = "checked"';
    echo 
    '<div>
   
 View All: <input type="checkbox" name="activeStatus" id="activeStatus" onChange="checkBoxStatusUser(this);" $statusMaintain/>
  </div>' ;
}
else
{
    $statusMaintain = 'unchecked = "unchecked"';
    echo 
    '<div>
   
 View All: <input type="checkbox" name="activeStatus" id="activeStatus" onChange="checkBoxStatusUser(this);" $statusMaintain/>
  </div>' ;
}
 ?>

Comment: DOn't put code in comments,its really hard to read. Create a new question if its a different bug else update your question